# Undo/ redo functionality in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on html `canvas` . I have implemented following features:

```
1) Simple Draw
2) Erasor
3) Shapes Draw
4) Shapes Resize
5) Shapes Move
6) Color Select
```

Now, I want to add `undo/redo` functionality.

Considering the above features implemented, I am thinking saving instance of entire `canvas` on every event execution. For example, on doing a `shape resize`, I push the entire canvas instance into an array.

When user clicks on `undo`, I simply, `pop` the last element from array, and repaint the `canvas`.

But, I am thinking saving the entire `canvas` instance everytime will be memory intensive and also not very optimal performance wise. Also, with this approach, I will have to limit the maximum number of `undo/redo` allowed. What would be the ideal number of `undo/redo` should I keep if I go ahead with this approach. Also, is there a better approach for this considering the above features.

Comment: A [command](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command) + [memento](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/memento) design pattern is usually the go-to starting place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `command` design pattern, and redraw your canvas from your history of commands.  You will be able to save a large amount of steps (hundreds if not thousands).

In a nutshell, instead of drawing to canvas directly, you will wrap your operation in a command that is added to a list, and then executed.  When the user wants to undo, you remove the last operation from the list, and replay it.  You can also keep the list intact and update an `index marker` to allow for redo.

In your case, you would also have commands for tool selection, so the selections would also be 'recorded' into your history.

Once you start using this pattern, you may find your entire application would be better structured using a `state` object, wrapped in a `store` that uses `commit` operations for all access.  Then you get the undo-redo for free.  See `redux`, `vuex`, and `flux` for the de facto standards of this `store` design.  As powerful as these libraries are, they are really lean and quite simple.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the command pattern is the [Memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) where you simply store the current state of the canvas every time an action is done. This requires more memory and generally will need to be restricted to small number of edits. Restoring an earlier state should be pretty fast though.

Comment: This is also the least error-prone way of doing undo; however as you said it requires a *lot* of memory.